# Download file from direct download link and save to server - PHP

Tags: php, server, download, mymaps

I use Google's My maps. The problem is that Google makes many restrictions in using their API, which makes it hard to insert or retrieve data from the map automatically.

I have a direct download link to this map file which downloads the KML file to any device when clicked.

What I want is a code in PHP to open this link, download the KML file and save it automatically to my server.

i have seen this in a different question but it didnt work for me:

```
shell_exec("wget -P /target/directory/ http://download.link.com/download.zip");
```

I think the problem is that my link does not link to a file (does not end in .zip or other file extensions)
This is an example for my link: [here](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1FcgdJK9tLMt_dygTbxObJHjyCoo&forcekml=1&cid=mp&cv=qDJ98FtrON4.he.)

Thank you!

Comment: Depeneding on googles restrictions, you could easily do this with curl (which avoids using exec at all costs), or even file_get_contents (if you have fopen wrappers enabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) functions, like so:

```
$path = "/target/directory/file.kml"; // Where the file should be saved to
$link = "https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml..."; // Download link
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($link));
```

Comment: simple and exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution to save the information into a file using cURL

```
 <?php

$ch = curl_init();

// You can add here the URL contains the information which should be fetched
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=1FcgdJK9tLMt_dygTbxObJHjyCoo&forcekml=1&cid=mp&cv=qDJ98FtrON4.he.');

// You can define the name which will be created with the extension, in this case it's .KML
$openFile = fopen('file.KML', 'w+');

// Here Curl will save the fetched information into the file.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $openFile);

curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

fclose($openFile);
```

Make sure you give permission to the folder on your server where the file will be created.